# How to add delay in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React.js. I am not sure how to add `delay` to render in React.js. What is the best way to add delay.

I am adding the following code in render but its not working.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   
}, 1000);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803440/delayed-rendering-of-react-components

Comment: Maybe you could instead describe the problem you are trying to solve because in JavaScript a delay is almost always the wrong approach.

Answer (score 54):

**Pure typescript Solution**

You would be able to create delay function with `async`:

```
function timeout(delay: number) {
    return new Promise( res => setTimeout(res, delay) );
}
```

And then call the function:

```
await timeout(1000); //for 1 sec delay
```

Comment: This should been part of the default javascript.

Comment: This is great and if you remove the `: number` by changing `function timeout(delay: number) {` to just `function timeout(delay) {`, then it becomes a Javascript solution instead of a Typescript solution.

Comment: This will block the rendering of your component, [this won't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65545256/542251). I wouldn't recommend this approach. Alans answer is better

Answer (score 36):

Not sure why you would want to do this, but something like this?

The component's constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        render: false //Set render state to false
    }
}
```

On component mount:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(function() { //Start the timer
      this.setState({render: true}) //After 1 second, set render to true
  }.bind(this), 1000)
}
```

The render method:

```
render() {
    let renderContainer = false //By default don't render anything
    if(this.state.render) { //If this.state.render == true, which is set to true by the timer.
        renderContainer = <div>Look at me! I'm content!</div> //Add dom elements
    }
    return (
      renderContainer //Render the dom elements, or, when this.state == false, nothing.
    )
  }
```

So when the timer fires, render is set to true. Because render is stored in `state`, this also triggers a re-render of the component. The `if` statement simply instructs `renderContainer` to not display anything unless the state render is true. You could also show a text indicating the component is loading, by instead of declaring `renderContainer= false` at the top, declaring the default as `renderContainer=<div>Component is loading..</div>` for example.

Comment: Testing a fast performing API against your UX when it's slow is always a nice to have. You don't want to throttle the connection of the test through dev-tools, because you're not testing how fast your app can pop-up and do stuff on devices, but rather what would happen if your API is slow and how those end users will handle it

Comment: Don't believe this solution automatically clears the timer set by setTimeout()? Wouldn't this result in memory leak?

Comment: @codeful.element setTimeout() fires the function just one time and does not need to be cleared. Using setInterval, the problem you describe could occur, as it executes the function until the timer is cleared. If you want to be really diligent, you should clear the timer on component dismount if it has not yet executed (although if it does, nothing will happen in this case as the component is already dismounted and wont be displayed).

Answer (score 26):

With React hooks. It will wait `5s` and then render this component.

```
import React from 'react'

const DeleayComponent = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setShow(true)
    }, 5000)

    return () => clearTimeout(timeout)

  }, [show])

  if (!show) return null

  return <>OK, Render</>
}

export default DeleayComponent
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to display a component after a time is conditional rendering like this :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        render: false 
    }
}
```

```
handleRender = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
     this.setState({ render : !this.state.render })
  }, 1000);
}

render () {
   return (
          <div>
             <button onClick={handleRender}>Set render to true</button>
             { this.state.render ? <Component /> : null }
          </div>
   )
}
```

When you click the button after one second it will set the render state to true and the `<Component />` will show up .

If you want to run setTimeout on component load and not clicking the button you can have it in `componentDidMount` lifecycle like this :

```
componentDidMount(){
  setTimeout(() => {
     this.setState({ render : !this.state.render })
  }, 1000);
}
```

Hope you fully understood how you can achieve this way of rendering components .

Answer (score 0):

One way to use hook with setTimeout is to set a property after the interval.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const BotResponse = () => {

......

const [botMessage, setBotMessage] = useState('');

// function called from some user interaction
const botResponse = (msg) => {
   setTimeout(function() {
      setBotMessage(msg);
   }, 500);
};

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("bot msg... " + botMessage);

    // display the bot message

}, [botMessage]); // listening to a change on this property
}
```