# Traverse jsx in variable, then render it by appending to ref

Tags: reactjs

I have a variable containing jsx such as this:

```
const data = (
    <>
        <CustomComponentA>
            Lorem ipsum
        </CustomComponentA>
        <CustomComponentB>
            dolor sit amet,
        </CustomComponentB>
        <CustomComponentA>
            consectetur adipiscing elit
        </CustomComponentA>
    </>
);
```

I want to traverse the above data one element at a time, then render the elements as follows:

```js
data.props.children.forEach(element => {
    myRef.current.append(element);
})
```

Problem:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Comment: Never try this before, But I think there are a few other better ways to do this. Why don't you put them in an array and render them with a map?

Comment: Needs to be rendered as shown by appending to DOM as rendering needs to happen with a time delay between each element.

Comment: Can you go with an approach like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42089548/how-to-add-delay-in-reactjs ?wrapping every delay component with the `DeleayComponent` hook as is shown in the first answer?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need an alternative approach to delaying. I am asking how to render by appending as outlined in my question.

Comment: @Ben, After a couple of tries and fails. I ended up with the solusion below. It works in the given live example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could try to use `renderToString` before appending the element to turn it into HTML:**

But before that, you will need to turn `HTML String` into an actual HTML object:

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';

data.props.children.forEach(element => {
    const htmlObject = document.createElement("div");
    htmlObject.innerHTML = renderToString(element);

    myRef.current.append(htmlObject.firstChild);
})
```

**Live working test:**

[image: Edit elastic-germain-kuvfr]

Comment: This is progress, but unfortunately it creates two DOM elements. Is there anyway around that?

Comment: What do you mean by `creates two DOM elements`? Isn't it still under the same root component?

Comment: The output of this will be `<div><markup for custom component>text</><div/>`. Is there a way to not have the outer div?

Comment: I see, Let's me figure that out.

Comment: Found the way man! Simply add `firstChild` to ignore wrapper parent, updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is the way!

Comment: Awesome! First time trying something like this, though

Comment: If you change `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` to `renderToString`, I will accept it as the answer!

Comment: Haha! Little mistake. Appreciate that, man