# React JS map an array with each item delayed

Tags: arrays, reactjs, asynchronous, settimeout, array.prototype.map

I have a React JS array with HTML element which works perfectly. Problem is that I aim to display this array with delayed rendering. Like:

First element goes instantly,

Second element goes +500ms

Third element goes +1000ms (second element + 500ms)

Fourth element goes +1500ms

and so on ...

Example code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';

const styles = {
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

function example(){
  let arr = [1,1,1,2,3,4]
  const res = arr.map((e,i) => 
setTimeout(() => {
  e === 1 ?
   <p>{e}</p> 
   :
  <p> Not one </p>
  },1000))
  return res
}


const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
    {example()}
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When I add setTimeout in the function, it gives me back only numbers not HTML elements.

Alternatively I can do this thing using SetInterval and state, but wondering if there is such a solution.

Regards,

Comment: Your example doesn't load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delayed rendering of React components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803440/delayed-rendering-of-react-components)

Comment: The result of setTimeout is a handle so you can cancel it, not the result of the method.   Methods called via setTimeout should not return a value, as it can't be captured.