# Too many renders error when trying to delay rendering a component using setTimeout in React

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, settimeout

So there is a parent & child component and I am setting cart items in local storage inside Parent component and want to access them in child components. Now the issue is that in child component , "cart is empty prompt" runs first even though I am extracting cart items from local storage. So I want to delay rendering of the child component by 2 sec so that the extracted cart items from the local storage are ready & get accessed first instead of running "cart is empty" prompt.

Here is the useEffect in child component in which i am extracting & checking for cart items -

```
var cartItems;

useEffect(() => {
if (localStorage.getItem("cartItems")) {
  cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"));
} else {
  Swal.fire({
    position: "center",
    icon: "info",
    title: "Cart Is Empty!",
    showConfirmButton: true,
  }).then(() => {
        navigate(-1);
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

Also cartItems is getting stored in local storage -

[image]

Here is the delay code which i took from ([Delayed rendering of React components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803440/delayed-rendering-of-react-components)) which wraps around my child component -

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Delayed = ({ children, delay, loader }) => {
 
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    var timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsShown(true);
    }, delay);

    return () => {clearTimeout(timer);}

  }, [delay]);


  return isShown ? children : loader;
}

export default Delayed
```

and finally my parent component -

```
<Delayed delay={2000} loader={<Loader />}>
     <Products/>
 </Delayed>
```

Also the 'setIsShown(true)' is causing the too many render problems , pointed in console.
Basic idea is that I would store cart items in local storage in parent component and then access them again in child component , i also tried passing the cart items as props but still the cart is empty prompt ran first , so it boils down to making the child component render after a delay to make the cartItems accessible. I am trying to resolve this issue from past couple of days but I had no luck. So I though of posting it here.Please help me resolve this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`?
The issue is not in your `Delayed` component, see this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-gwen-2twuv?file=/src/Delayed.tsx).
I also need to mention, that it's bad practice to delay a ui-element.

Comment: thank you @foxxycodes for responding , i have never used useLayoutEffect i have only heard about it.How it is different from useEffect?

Comment: @BhaveshDamor Refer to this link by Kent C. Dodds: [useEffect vs useLayoutEffect](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect). Simply put, useLayoutEffect calculates before the first paint of your component, which may solve your problem.

Comment: i was reading the same article.I will learn more about it but you mentioned that delaying a ui-element is a bad practice, could you elaborate more about it?

Comment: There is no use case to delay a users UI except maybe for a game, imo. If you for example fetch a website, than that's an asynchronous operation, which means that it returns a `Promise`. `Promises` can be awaited and one can react respectively to them. So if it would take time to get data from anywhere, you would display a loader-component until the data is finally loaded, then the data can be displayed.
Basically it all comes down to: "Should i let my users wait for a set amount of time, if i could also just let them wait as long as it takes to get the data?"